# Do I need a transit visa in Canada?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, yyz

I'm traveling to India from the US, I've a F1 visa in the US and I'm an Indian national. My flight is through YYZ (Toronto Pearson International Airport), a layover more than an hour there.

Do I need to get a transit visa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do. From the [Government of Canada's official website](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/twov/travellers.asp):

> Nationals from the following countries qualify for the Transit Without
>   Visa (TWOV) program:
>
> - Indonesia
> - Thailand
> - Taiwan
> - Philippines